# Does Server Fault plan to support IPv6?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred

IPv6 is an up-and-coming [topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ipv6) on Server Fault, especially since IPv4 address space exhaustion [finally occurred](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_address_exhaustion) for some parts of the world.

Yet I can't help noticing that serverfault.com has no AAAA record. Are there any plans to support IPv6? If not yet on a permanent basis, then perhaps for [World IPv6 day](http://isoc.org/wp/worldipv6day/)?

Comment: I am not a ServerFault admin, but considering they're using HAProxy for a bunch of stuff (http://blog.serverfault.com/post/stack-exchanges-architecture-in-bullet-points/), and HAProxy IPv6 support is still evolving, I'm guessing they're not going to participate on IPv6 day.

Comment: +1 - I was planning on asking a similar question myself :)

Comment: Why? In real and practical terms, why?

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86227/world-ipv6-day/86234#86234

Comment: @John: Because it's shiny!

Comment: @John - because, eventually it's going to have to be accessible by IPv6. Maybe not in the next 2-3 years, but why not lead by example at making the internet better (and IPv6 will make it better, gooooooodbye NAT)

Comment: @Mark, what;'s the rush? I can't see IPv4 disappearing for at least another decade, by which time Stack Exchange may either no longer exist or have evolved into something else. NAT is a separate issue altogether and is not all bad. In fact it has a number of advantages that make my job easier.

Comment: @John - well, there's no rush even as the SE guys have pointed out, they'll *think* about doing it next year. The real issue with IPv6 adoption is that nobody has really comitted to it, and until some big players do it won't get anywhere. Google have IPv6 as an opt-in, as do Facebook, but I don't know of any other big players. I actually think that the SE sites, being focussed very heavilly on highly technical people, might actually see an above average amount of IPv6 traffic (most sites report < 1% IPv6 traffic, so 1% would be a huge increase)

Comment: "IPv6 Day" has now been and gone and I couldn't help but notice that it was one of the worlds greatest ever non-events. :)

Comment: IPv6 day coming and going without notice is a bug, not a feature.  As far as why it should be done, it's because we're basically out of IPv4 space but people are still wanting new servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are thinking about IPv6 implementation, however as of right now we don't have the resources to dedicate to this. As we continue to evolve our network we'll keep an eye on IPv6 implementation.

We have internally discussed implementing it, and at the very least at some point this year we'll look into the effort and what needs to be done to get IPv6 running.

Comment: Any thoughts on this since then?

Comment: @FalconMomot nothing new. It's still on our list, but honestly a low priority. We did get an allocation from ARIN so that's something.